# Java Code Throwing Errors, Can't Find Why

Tags: java

Below is my code I am using for a project. I am designing a probability simulation to allow the user to input number of outcomes, name the outcomes, input the probability of each outcome, input number of trials, and then run the simulation and print the results. I am having some issues with out of bounds exceptions when interpreting the results of Math.random().

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

out("Welcome to Probability Simulator. How many outcomes would you like to generate?");
int numOfVars = scan.nextInt();
outln("");

String[] outcomes  = new String[numOfVars];
int[] outcomeCount = new int[numOfVars];
double[] probabilities = new double[numOfVars];

for (int i = 0; i < numOfVars; i++) {

  out("Enter outcome " + (i + 1) + "'s name: ");
  outcomes[i] = scan.next();
  outln("");

  probabilities[i] = -1;

}

for (int i = 0; i < numOfVars; i++) {

  while (!(probabilities[i] > 0 && probabilities[i] < 1)) {

    out("Enter probability for " + outcomes[i] + " (must be between 0 and 1, exclusive): ");
    probabilities[i] = scan.nextDouble();
    outln("");

  }

}

for (int i = 1; i < numOfVars; i++) {

  probabilities[i] += probabilities[i - 1];

}

int numOfResults = 0;

while (numOfResults < 2) {

  out("How many results would you like to generate? (must be more than one)");
  numOfResults = scan.nextInt();
  outln("");

}

int[] results = new int[numOfResults];
double[] random = new double[numOfResults];

for (int i = 0; i < numOfResults; i++) {

  random[i] = Math.random();

}

for (int i = 0; i < random.length; i++) {

  if (random[i] < probabilities[0])
    outcomeCount[0]++;
  else if (random[i] >= probabilities[probabilities.length - 2])
    outcomeCount[probabilities.length - 1]++;
  else {
    for (int n = 1; n < probabilities.length - 1; n++) {

      if (random[i] >= probabilities[n] && random[i] < probabilities[n + 1])
        outcomeCount[i]++;

    }

  }

}


for (int i = 0; i < probabilities.length; i++){

  System.out.println(probabilities[i]);

}

outln("");

for (int i = 0; i < numOfVars; i++){

  System.out.println(outcomeCount[i]);

}

outln("");

for (int i = 0; i < random.length; i++){

  System.out.println(random[i]);

}

scan.close();
```

}

public static void out(String text) {

```
System.out.print(text);
```

}

public static void outln(String text) {

```
System.out.println(text);
```

}

This is the exception.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
at ProbabilitySimulation.main(ProbabilitySimulation.java:83)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:267)
```

In addition, when using more than 2 outcomes and an error isn't thrown, the outcomeCount array doesn't add up to the number of results desired.

I can't quite figure out why this is happening. I am a java beginner, so useful feedback is appreciated, but please take it easy :)

(Yes, I know it's generally bad practice to use separate methods as shortcuts for System.out.print, but it was one of the project requirements.)

Comment: The code is hard to read; the errors are hard to visualize using only your verbal description.  What do you see?  What do you expect?  Array bounds errors are easy to find with a debugger.

Comment: @duffymo I expect for the program to generate an amount of random numbers equivalent to the number of trials the user desires, then compare that to the probabilities given at the beginning. From there, it increments variables within the outcomeCount array based on where the random number falls in the probability distribution. The problem I'm experiencing is that I'm getting an out of bound exception when incrementing, as well as the final sum of all outcomeCounts not adding to the number of trials.

Comment: I see.  You've got a problem with your arrays.  It'll be easy to find in a debugger; faster than asking here.  Learning to debug is a key skill to cultivate and practice.

Comment: Including the exception stack trace would help a lot here. It should tell you what line it was generated on which would help a ton because you have so many spots where array indices are used.

Comment: @duffymo I'm only familiar with DrJava unfortunately, as it is what we are limited to in class. What do you suggest doing to debug?

Comment: @kunruh Added that in the original post.

Comment: Your program ran just fine for me

Comment: @pruntlar Did you use varying numbers of outcomes and trials?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Just 16 pages into the DrJava manual -- "The Debugger" - http://www.drjava.org/docs/quickstart.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Changed the assignment to outcomeCount to work as follows.

```
for (int i = 0; i < random.length; i++) {

  if (random[i] / (probabilities[0] * 10) < 1)
    outcomeCount[0]++;

  else {

    for (int n = 1; n < numOfVars; n++) {

      if (random[i] >= (probabilities[n - 1] * 10) && random[i] < (probabilities[n] * 10))
            outcomeCount[n]++;

    }

  }

}
```

No longer throws errors, and properly assigns outcomes to the respective categories. Thanks for the help those of you who suggested debugging!